# I m using HP notebook 2000 laptop and i cant enable wifi

Tags: wireless

this is optput of iwconfig

```
$ iwconfig

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

eno1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

this is output of ifconfig

```
$ ifconfig 
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.6  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 fe80::d0f4:1f5e:9e5:145d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 10:1f:74:4b:07:59  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 4103  bytes 2653424 (2.6 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 4268  bytes 863771 (863.7 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 668  bytes 53376 (53.3 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 668  bytes 53376 (53.3 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

this is output of rfkill list all

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

this is output of dmesg | grep rt2

```
$ dmesg | grep rt2
[   44.979845] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 5390, 
rev 0502 detected
[   45.012984] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 5390 
detected
[   45.628017] rt2800pci 0000:07:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
```

this is output of lsmod

```
lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
appletalk              36864  0
ipx                    28672  0
p8023                  16384  1 ipx
psnap                  16384  2 appletalk,ipx
p8022                  16384  1 ipx
llc                    16384  2 p8022,psnap
snd_hda_codec_realtek    90112  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
snd_hda_codec         126976  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  4   snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102400  3 
snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
arc4                   16384  2
videodev              172032  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
rt2800pci              16384  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
rt2800mmio             16384  1 rt2800pci
kvm_amd              2179072  0
kvm                   593920  1 kvm_amd
rt2800lib              94208  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
rt2x00pci              16384  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio             16384  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
rt2x00lib              53248  5 
rt2800lib,rt2x00pci,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio,rt2800pci
mac80211              782336  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00pci,rt2x00lib
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
input_leds             16384  0
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
cfg80211              602112  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
joydev                 20480  0
memstick               16384  1 rtsx_pci_ms
serio_raw              16384  0
snd                    77824  16 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rt2800pci
k10temp                16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
i2c_piix4              24576  0
mac_hid                16384  0
hp_wireless            16384  0
binfmt_misc            20480  1
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              24576  0
x_tables               36864  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
uas                    24576  0
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
usb_storage            69632  2 uas
amdkfd                139264  1
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
psmouse               139264  0
radeon               1507328  57
r8169                  81920  0
mii                    16384  1 r8169
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 radeon
rtsx_pci               57344  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
ttm                    98304  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper        151552  1 radeon
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  2
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   352256  7 radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
libahci                32768  1 ahci
wmi                    16384  0
video                  40960  0
fjes                   73728  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possibly driver/firmware issues my friend.

Try this

sudo apt-get install firmware-ralink

let me know what happens.

**or**

Try a usb wifi card and see if the usb wifi device shows up in ifconfig .

iwconfig is showing your internal card but its been my experience when working with a card that doesn't have supported drivers/firmware it will show in iwconfig but not ifconfig. also I see this is a problematic chipset RT5390 for linux

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install firmware-ralink
[sudo] password for priyank: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package firmware-ralink